# Scanner bug in java

Tags: java

I'm italian (the writings in the prints are in italian). After do the addition, the program ask me an input, and from this input (and another that it ask after) it made an subtraction. I don't know if this is a bug. Can somone help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calcolatrice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numero1;
        int numero2;
        int numero3;

        System.out.println("Menu: "
                + "addition (1), "
                + "subtraction (2), "
                + "multiplication (3), "
                + "division (4), "
                + "exponential (5), "
                + "square root (6)");
        System.out.println("\nEnter the number corresponding to the option you want: ");
        int opzione = input.nextInt();

        if (opzione == 1) {
            System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
            numero1 = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
            numero2 = input.nextInt();

            numero3 = numero1 + numero2;
            System.out.print("The sum between " + numero1 + " and " + numero2 + " is: " + numero3);

        } else if (opzione == 2)
            System.out.print("\nEnter the first number: ");

        numero1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
        numero2 = input.nextInt();

        numero3 = numero1 - numero2;
        System.out.print("The difference between " + numero1 + " and " + numero2 + " is: " + numero3);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/2970947)

Comment: Did you write this code? Do you know what it does?

Comment: Your question is *really* unclear. Please tell us what you think should happen given some specific input and what happens instead.

Comment: you did not wrap the code after "else if" into curly braces, so only one line is a part of if statement (which is also a valid syntax)

Comment: The code works fine. There is no bug, or critter, or anything

Comment: @DevilsHnd your edit has *removed* the error :-( ||  Original is missing a `{` after `else if (option == 2)` and the corresponding closing `}` ! Maybe not the best idea to change the code

Comment: Maybe...but I'll decide that.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Since you removed the error, no meaningful answer can be supplied. With that the question will get closed, Diego did not learn anything and the meaning of Stackoverflow can be questioned. Please decide wisely.

Comment: I don't get it. The code seems fine. I ran it with input "2" (subtraction), then "5" and "1" and it printed the result of "5-1" which is 4. Then the program stopped. What's the problem?

Comment: @Kaan you must test the code originally posted by OP, not the edited one - DevilsHnd translated the code from Italian, but also **corrected** the original error!

Comment: Not sure best path forward, but seems either: restore OP’s original question (including bugs in code), or close this question altogether and OP creates a new question with the same initial question.

Comment: I posted another edit – bug in the original code is once again present.

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, you have this logic:

```
if (opzione == 1) {
    // do things
} else if (opzione == 2)
    // do other things
```

That code has a subtle bug present: in the second branch of the `if` statement, there are no braces; that is, there is not `{...}`.

Here is the entire block, where I applied code formatting (indendation) as well as line numbers:

```
1   if (opzione == 1) {
2       System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
3       numero1 = input.nextInt();
4   
5       System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
6       numero2 = input.nextInt();
7   
8       numero3 = numero1 + numero2;
9       System.out.print("The sum between " + numero1 + " and " + numero2 + " is: " + numero3);
10  
11  } else if (opzione == 2)
12      System.out.print("\nEnter the first number: ");
13  
14  numero1 = input.nextInt();
15  
16  System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
17  numero2 = input.nextInt();
18  
19  numero3 = numero1 - numero2;
20  System.out.print("The difference between " + numero1 + " and " + numero2 + " is: " + numero3);
```

A few comments:

- Line 12: This is indented once, which corresponds to the `if` statement – that is, if `opzione` has a value of 2, it will then proceed to run line 12.
- Line 14: This is not indented. Note that the code formatter did this automatically (I'm using IntelliJ, though there are many other options). The formatter understood that line 14 is *not* part of the `if` statement from line 11.
- Lines 16-20: Just like with line 14, these are lines of that code that run independently of the `if` statements on line 1 or line 11. This is why you observed that it prompts you for additional things after choosing the "addition" path.

To fix your code:

- Line 11: Add an open brace (`{`) at the end of the line, changing this:

  ```
  } else if (opzione == 2)
  ```

  to this:

  ```
  } else if (opzione == 2) {
  ```
- Line 21: Add a new line at the end (after the call to `System.out.print`), with a single closing brace (`}`) – this is the other end of `{` from Line 11